# serial input buffer size Matlab

Tags: matlab, buffer

I'm trying to read a lot of data coming from my Arduino, I've set my input buffer to 500000 to make sure that it can handle all these data. My data are 4 sensors readings each samples at 250 Hz. With the default buffer size (712), I used to get snags when I plot the readings in real time and the samples get disordered which makes the plot go crazy. I solved this by increasing the buffer size to 50000. But now, this will work for a while but if I want to run it for 15 minutes, I get the same misbehavior after 5 minutes, with the addition that the plotting gets slower. I do have some processing code along with the live plotting but it shouldn't be like this with such a bi buffer. I want to know whether the buffer will contain all the data from the beginning until it's full or will it keep erasing older data when it gets full (knowing that I already saved it in another vector and plotted it). I truly don't understand why this keeps happening.

kind regards
I.H

Comment: "_I do have some processing code along with the live plotting but it shouldn't be like this with such a big buffer_". The size of the buffer does not impact the speed of your processing. If your processing for a chunk of data takes longer than the chunk of data takes to arrive ... then even an infinite buffer will not stop the gradual de-synchronisation between the data arrival and their display.

Answer (score 0):

When the buffer gets full, once you get new data it erases the old data. The behavior you are seeing is because your processing and your plotting is slower than the flow of the data.

- Try to make sure that you optimize you processing
- Make sure that for plotting is done by "drawnow". Like this you are sure that if there is anything in the queue it is not executed
- Try to avoid saving and keeping all the data
- If the problem is still there, you can try to implement a timer to make sure that you are consistent with reading your data

Comment: How do I erase data when the buffer is used by the program? In the documentation, flushing the buffer erases all the data. I'm sure there will still be some new data that I haven't read yet when I flush it, which means loosing data.....I'm using drawnow and updating the plots every 70 samples for faster processing.  the other signal processing part may be time consuming but that's because I'm doing heavy processing......finally, how should the timer figure out whether I'm consistent or not?

Comment: If you are reading a serial port, once you read, the data is removed. You don't need to erase anything!